# Python, проблема с кодировкой или шифрованием

Tags: python

Получаю данные с формы:
`login = self.lineLogin.text()`
Кодирую с помощью модуля `base64`:
`base64.b64encode(str.encode(login))`
Вношу шифрованный логин в кэш.
При открытии клиента, отправляю расшифрованый логин из кэша на сервер с модулем `socket`.
На сервере возникла ошибка, из за того что ДБ возвращала `None`, при верном условии.
Проверил с помощью сравнения.
`if login != "login123"`, где `#login123` пример введённого логина, условие проходит, хотя на человеческом языке строки одинаковы. Я знал что есть множество проблем с кодировками, но как их решить? Почему одинаковые строки - разные?

Примечание: ошибок в переводе строк в байты и обратно нет. `decode()` и `str.encode` везде где нужно проставлены.

Comment: Не факт что ошибка именно в кодировке, но всё же попробуйте изначально все входные данные переводить в utf-8